# How can I execute a jar file included in c++ with a Base64 string without write it on the HDD?

Tags: c++, jar, include, base64, shellexecute

How I can execute a jar file included in my c++ exe file in a Base64 string without write it on the HDD?
Is it possibile execute it from memory or something like this without have 2 files on the HDD?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the reason for avoiding the HDD?

Comment: The OS may place parts of your program on the HDD and only load them as necessary.  Thus your program may be using the HDD anyway.

Comment: my idea was like launch4j but i have no idea how works it because launch4j exe has been detected as virus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JNI:

- Create a JVM instance.
- Create a ByteArrayInputStream on the decoded
  base64 jar string.
- Create a JarInputStream and pass it the
  ByteArrayInputStream.
- Iterate each jarEntry in the JarInputStream and
  load the class with a ClassLoader.
- Store each class in a HashMap for
  quick access.

Another way is to call JNI's:

`jclass DefineClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name, jobject loader,
const jbyte *buf, jsize bufLen);`

**Example:** https://github.com/Brandon-T/Cpp-JVM

I added the example to my Github since it was way too large to fit on StackOverflow. Note: You do not need the JNI wrapper that I wrote. It would cut down on code by a ton if you use raw JNI.

The wrapper is there from some legacy code I wrote a long time ago and I decided to just use it and have it keep track of the JavaVM and JNIEnv for me.

**EDIT:** Beware that I hardcoded the path to libJVM and libJNI:

https://github.com/Brandon-T/Cpp-JVM/blob/master/JVM.cpp#L41 because I couldn't get the JVM running on OSX without it.

Comment: can you write an exmple? Is the first time that i use JNI on C++, I've read some tutorials but I don't understand how do this

Comment: @MarcoEliteC98 Added an example.